# Headset has to be re-pluged after rebooting

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, headset

I'm using the version 16.04 LTS of Ubuntu and after rebooting my PC, I have to unplug and plug back in my headset (Jabra UC voice 150a) to the USB port in order for it to show up in my audio settings and be usable. Curiously the mic of the headset shows up in the source (input) with no problems. I tried to delete the folder `~/.conf/pulse` but it didn't work. Executing this command: `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` the headset shows up.

Could anyone help me?

Ps: I'm new to Linux.

Comment: Can you add more details to your post? What version of Ubuntu are you using? Also, welcome to Linux!

Comment: I have found those Jabra UC voice to be somewhat touchy in regards to linux. IIRC, they were designed to be "Skype for business" compatible. I have a friend who is having a similar issue with his headset.

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush, Thanks for your quick reply. I edited my post putting the version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A coworker has the same Ubuntu version of mine and has no problem with that headset. Is there any file that I could compare in order to find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting these commands in the /etc/rc.local file just before `exit 0` command:

`pulseaudio -k 
alsa force-reload`