# jabra headset shows up in dmesg but not in audio

Tags: usb, sound

I have a USB Jabra headset, shows up in dmesg

```
[    3.452504] usb 1-1.4: Product: Jabra UC VOICE 550a
    [    3.452506] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Jabra
    [    3.680774] input: Jabra Jabra UC VOICE 550a as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:0349.0004/input/input8
    [    3.800453] hid-generic 0003:0B0E:0349.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [Jabra Jabra UC VOICE 550a] on usb-0000:00:12.2-1.4/input3
    [   44.204920] usb 1-1.4: Product: Jabra UC VOICE 550a
    [   44.204924] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Jabra
    [   44.468008] input: Jabra Jabra UC VOICE 550a as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:0349.0005/input/input19
    [   44.524997] hid-generic 0003:0B0E:0349.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [Jabra Jabra UC VOICE 550a] on usb-0000:00:12.2-1.4/input3
    [   47.761324] usb 1-1.4: Product: Jabra UC VOICE 550a
    [   47.761328] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Jabra
    [   48.023719] input: Jabra Jabra UC VOICE 550a as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:0349.0006/input/input20
    [   48.080988] hid-generic 0003:0B0E:0349.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [Jabra Jabra UC VOICE 550a] on usb-0000:00:12.2-1.4/input3
    [   56.348881] usb 1-1.4: Product: Jabra UC VOICE 550a
    [   56.348885] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Jabra
    [   56.614105] input: Jabra Jabra UC VOICE 550a as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.3/0003:0B0E:0349.0007/input/input21
    [   56.673145] hid-generic 0003:0B0E:0349.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.00 Device [Jabra Jabra UC VOICE 550a] on usb-0000:00:12.2-1.4/input3
    [   58.545355] usb 1-1.4: Product: Jabra UC VOICE 550a
    [   58.545357] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Jabra
```

But not in audio

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction to troubleshoot?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Does [https://askubuntu.com/questions/937432/headset-has-to-be-re-pluged-after-rebooting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937432/headset-has-to-be-re-pluged-after-rebooting) seem similar to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Jabra GN headphone, this problem was solved as follows

in the terminal go to this path

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

create the following file, with the following content

```
sudo nano 50-jabra.conf
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Jabra"
        MatchProduct "GN Netcom A/S Jabra EVOLVE LINK MS"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

otherwise you can download the file

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/259700341/50-jabra.conf
```

reboot with no usb devices being connected and wait because it may take some time more, login to ubuntu and wait till it has completely bootet, then connect your device

you should see now a second icon in system->sound->Jabra Device

Comment: Had 550a headset operational with output only. Tried this for getting the microphone to work, and it did, but now no output.

Comment: unfortunately, i dont have access to this pc any more, if it worked for you, give thumb up. However, i remember that it used to work fine after this settings. May be you are trying to work with teams ? in teams there is a special button to use the jabra. But as long as the file is in its location, in X11 and the Linux Gui (x11) is working properly, it should work. There are some cases, i saw, in which this work arount did not even work at all. Unfortunately, Jabra did not offer much support in this. I hope i can help more.

Comment: I put it aside for now, still not working. I will get back to it soon.